# Third level inheritance doesn't work

Tags: javascript, inheritance, coffeescript

I have a few classes in CoffeeScript, that inherit from another class. The chain looks like this:

- `Page`

  - `ChooserPage`

    - `YesNoChooserPage`
  - `CommentPage`
  - `SimplePage`

This works beautifully but when I try to introduce one more level to the ChooserPage-chain, specifically `MultipleYesNoChooserPage extends YesNoChooserPage`, suddenly I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

I checked the existence of the classes and got the following results:

- `Page` exists
- `ChooserPage` exists
- `YesNoChooserPage` doesn't exist (undefined)
- `MultipleYesNoChooserPage` doesn't exist (undefined, obviously)

**To compare:**
Without MultipleYesNoChooserPage defined:
[image]

With MultipleYesNoChooserPage defined:
[image]

Does CoffeeScript have some maximum limit I don't know of (and cannot find anything) or is there any other reason for that?

The classes are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: Sounds odd. Do you have a more complete code example?

Comment: `MultipleYesNoChooserPage` doesn't even have additional or override-functions, yet. It already breaks simply by existing. If I leave it out, everything works just fine. Also, If I change `MultipleYesNoChooserPage` to extend any other `Page`-based class, I don't get any error (but I also do not get any functionality then, of course).

Comment: Please post text, not images. Include a minimal example of code that produces the failure.

Comment: Code examples of the definitions would be more useful than sample output.

Comment: The class definitions look exactly like specified in the list/tree above. I can't seem to be able to reproduce this outside of the project, which confuses me even more.

Comment: "I can't seem to be able to reproduce this outside of the project" which is a clear indicator the problem has nothing to do with the inheritance level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution, which happened by chance.

While trying to reproduce this I noticed that it doesn't happen outside the project. Because it confused me even more (I mean, how can the simple existence of a class let another one vanish) I completely deleted the file and re-created it. It worked, which let my confusion rise to an uncomprehensible level. Then it struck me:

To force the order of the files being loaded, they are named rather odd. In this case, this is what YesNoChooserPage and MultipleYesNoChooserPage are named like:

- YesNoChooserPage.coffee
- YZMultipleYesNoChooserPage.coffee

My editor (Sublime Text) lists them in the intended order but I noticed, the terminal doesn't. When I recreated the file, I accidentally named it 'YzMultipleYesNoChooserPage', causing a different order. This then worked.

Learned yet another thing.